# How are these two higher-order functions different?

Tags: scala

The following two higher-order functions yield the same result, but I'm having trouble understanding the difference between the two. In fact, I don't understand 1). How can a function have two sets of `()`?

1)

```
def sum(f: Int => Int) (a: Int, b: Int) = {
    def loop(a: Int, acc: Int) : Int =
        if (a > b) acc
        else loop (a + 1, f(a) + acc)
    loop (a, 0)
}
```

2)

```
def sum(f: Int => Int,  a: Int, b: Int) = {
      def loop(a: Int, acc: Int) : Int =
        if (a > b) acc
        else loop (a + 1, f(a) + acc)
      loop (a, 0)
}
```

Comment: Scala functions can have multiple parameter lists (as in your first defintion of `sum`). See http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/currying.html

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first function is curried. Meaning you can partially apply it more easily. If you only use the first parameter list the function returns another function with the signature `(Int, Int) => Int`.

This is really useful if you need to pass a function with a specific function signature to higher order functions like `map` or `reduce`.

In other functional programming languages like Haskell, all functions are curried by default.
I wrote a whole blog post on this topic in case you're interested. You can read it [right here.](http://lukajcb.github.io/blog/scala/2016/03/08/a-real-world-currying-example.html)

Comment: Can you post your blog link? Thanks

Comment: So only 2) is high order function. And 1) is not? 1) is currying instead?

Comment: No, a higher order function is a function that takes a function as a parameter, like `map`, `filter` or `reduce`. So 2) is a normal function and 1) is the same function, but curried. :)

Comment: Correction, both 1) and 2) are higher order functions, but only 1) is curried :)